# Trying to TestFlight, but ITC bundle IDs screwed up somehow

Tags: app-store-connect, bundle-identifier

I'm trying to upload my app to TF it with some friends.

In iTunes Connect I went to My Apps, hit + and entered my new app. I put in my bundle ID - the complete "reverse URL". That takes you to a more detailed App Information page, where my Bundle ID was different - instead of the "reverse URL", it has the application name twice...

```
App-Name - App-Name
```

Is this normal? When I try to upload it complains that the bundle id doesn't exist:

iTunes Store operation failed.
No suitable application records were found. Verify your bundle identifier 'com.apath.App-Name' is correct.

When I tried to make a new app with that identifier it said it already had that ID.

Comment: Did you create the app already in the Apple Developer Center? (https://developer.apple.com/account)

Comment: Oh yes I should close this... the problem was some strange event in the ITC UI - I managed to enter the ID without the reverse-URL, just the name itself. I created a new one in the certs area in dev.app.com, deleted the old one, and was off to the races